# How to convert int to string in Expression Language?

Tags: jsf, xpages, el

I am working in XPages (JSF View controller).  In my DataTable, I want to create a html attribute `data-dmrkey="##"`

Here is the XML Markup on the page.  Builds fine.

```
<xp:attr name="data-dmrkey" value="#{rowData.dmrkey}"></xp:attr>
```

At runtime I get this message

> javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.lang.Long incompatible with java.lang.String
>           javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:865)
>           com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.invokeOnComponent(UIDataPanelBase.java:416)

Is there a Expression Language way to convert this primitive type to a String?

Comment: The current work around is adding a method getDisplayDmrkey() and binding to rowData.displayDmrkey in the wrapper class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this question has been out here a while, but this will work:

```
value="0#{rowData.drmKey}"
```

This takes advantage of the way java auto-converts numbers to string when concatenating. When calculating that value it returns "0"+rowData.drmKey, which converts it to a String with a leading zero - which can then be parsed back into a Long (or Integer, etc.)

Comment: this works avoiding the exception error, but warning that it concatenates a zero to whatever the object returns.  You may have to strip off the leading '0' if that causes issues matching.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about converting to String in EL, but if you change the expression to JavaScript, the attribute works OK:

```
<xp:attr name="someAttr" value="#{javascript:rowData.getColumnValue('someIntField')}"/>
```

Comment: The object rowData is a Java object model wrapper, data is from the AS400.  what I have been doing is creating in the wrapper class , a method like getDisplayDmrkey() and return the string value.

Comment: Maire, can you contribute to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41877024/devops-with-xpages-on-premesis-or-paas-like-bluemix